# Generating a flat array from nested for loops in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I'm building a 'Deck' class, modeled after a standard deck of playing cards.

What I WANT is an array of 52 cards, with every possible combination of suits and ranks.

What I GET is an array of length 4, each element of which is an array of 13 objects.

CODE:

```
ranks = [1..13]                                                                                                                       
suits = ["S", "H", "D", "C"]          

cards = ({rank: rank, suit: suit} for rank in ranks for suit in suits)
```

Now I know that I can get the job done by declaring an empty array and pushing to it with each iteration, but that doesn't seem as elegant as using the return value of the `for`.  (This is a pet project, so just getting it to work is not the only goal.)

What is the elegant solution here?  How do I get the `for` statement to return a flat array of each combination of cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
cards = [].concat ({rank: rank, suit: suit} for rank in ranks for suit in suits)...
```

Comment: Hm.. that still leaves 'cards' with length 4, on my version of coffeescript.. (v1.7.1)

Comment: Oh, wait.. I didn't notice the '...'.  This is interesting.  It does work, so thanks for the answer!